# JavaScript detect enter event in WYSIWYG tool vs. a textarea

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, slack

I am working on a plugin for Slack and making good progress.  For the Slack input bar (shown below) I can now "convert" recognized words in user's text into links by `addEventListener` for a click to the submit button.

[image]

[image]

Then (based on the HTML structure of the Slack entry tool), I can capture the <p> elementNode containing the user text this way:

```js
// don't laugh, it works reliably
e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[1].firstChild.firstChild.firstChild
```

and convert it upon submission.

Since the element is a <p> and the user is using a WYSIWYG editor, I need to also capture `<Enter>`, but I can't bind it to the `<p>` element since that doesn't have an `onkeypress` event (like a textarea).

Is there a way to capture the `<Enter>` event when in the wysiwyg so behave the same as the click event on the button?  I know there are many JavaScript event features I'm not yet aware of.

Comment: You can use the html 5 `content-editable` attribute to enable typing (and receiving key events) directly from a P tag.

Comment: I tested this on a simple HTML file and it works in that context.  However, it doesn't work on Slack as I think my cursor is really on some overlay and what I'm typing is interpreted into that <p>.  I tried it and it didn't work, however trying it on just a random <div> on the page _did_ work.  Great idea, I still need to do some digging though.